# ASP.net core 2.1 not loading in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

Im having an issue with a aspnet dotnet core 2.1 app not running in IIS.
There nothing in the event viewer, the server simply isnt responding (chrome states "[hostname] failed to connect."

- Ive installed visual c++ 2015 version 3.
- Ive installed dotnet-hosting-2.1.3-win.
- Ive rebooted my machine
- I've restarted IIS
- Ive created the directory "logs/stdout".
- Ive set stdoutLogEnabled="true" to see if I could get an error message.
- Ive configured the appool to be "no managed code".
- Ive set the app pool to run as an administrator user.
- Ive set permissions on the application directory to everyone recursively.
- Ive checkd under sites[mysite]\modules to ensure "AspNetCoreModule" is listed there and it is.

But nothing I do gives me any information to go on.

If I run the app via "dotnet.exe ./[application].dll" it is started on port 5000 and I can browse to it and it works just fine.

What step am I missing?  How can I get a proper response from IIS to see what the error is?

This is a Windows Server 2016 machine.  Same results on my Windows 10 dev box.

Update: Ive followed https://neelbhatt.com/2018/01/30/deploy-net-core-application-to-iis-step-by-step-guide/ and same results.   Cant get it to load at all.

Comment: did you use the publish option to get it to your windows server?

Comment: tried publish from vs and also dotnet publish -c Release.  Just copied output to server and manually configured IIS.  I'm going to need to package this up in an installer, so need to get the steps/prereqs figured out first.

Comment: I even tried create a new mvc app from visual studio, using that template, publishing that and running that.  Neither work.  So looks like not my code, but the server/windows 10/IIS configuration.

Really isnt helpful that there is no output at all...

Comment: What's the site bindings on IIS? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html and what is the URL in your web browser?

Comment: I just have a custom hostname set on port 80.  so browsing to "http://[mysite]".

I just added an additionally binding on a different port, and it works... I forgot to update my host file.  That was super dumb of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a custom hostname, but forgot to update the host file.  Well that was stupid of me.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with publish on asp.net core 2.1 can be fixed as following.
Put code below on web.config that is generated after publish and give a try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
        arguments=".\Web.dll"
        stdoutLogEnabled="false"
        stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```